# ElasticBeanstalk with Docker: how to use create-environment from aws cli

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm trying to use aws cli to create a new environment for Docker. I can do this easily enough through the aws web console, but there I have to choose from the dropdowns "type: WebServer" and "configuration: Docker". I can't see where these options exist in the `aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment` [arguments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-environment.html). (I don't see them in the `--option-settings` [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html) either.) Is there a working sample for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not given this a shot but I assume there's a `--solution-stack-name` option where you can pass values such as `64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.1 running Docker 1.6.0`. You can alternatively specify the solution stack on json file and specify the json file via `--option-settings file://your_options.json` where you can include other options apart from solution stack

`{
"SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.1 running Docker 1.6.0"
}`

You can see the values possible to use over here: docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html

Comment: Yes, I got it working with --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.1 running Docker 1.6.0". Worked perfectly. (But I'm not sure you're right about being able to put it in the your_options.json file instead. I don't see that option listed in the docs and when I tried your suggested syntax it choked.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder with Dockerrun.aws.json.

In `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` add

```
global:
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.1 running Docker 1.6.0
```

Use the *eb* command: `eb init && eb create`

[How to install eb.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html)

Comment: Are you suggesting installing the eb cli separately from the AWS cli? I thought that the specific cli's were being deprecated so you could now run all eb commands using "aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment..." etc.

Comment: Well, if you didn't have that other winning answer :) But I merely said what worked for me; I'm a newbie in aws myself, but I thought it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see name of stacks available in AWS through this command:

**aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks**

At moment the last docker image is **64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.10.0 running Docker 17.12.1-ce**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html

After that you created a Elastic Beanstalk application perform the command below to create environment

aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment --application-name MyApp --environment-name my-env --cname-prefix my-app1 --version-label v1 --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.10.0 running Docker 17.12.1-ce"